# Power supply inductor replacement

Tags: power-supply, inductor

First of all I apologize for noob question.

I have broken IKEA ICPSH120-0.5EU power supply. Output is 4.0V 120mA.
I have replaced the bridge rectifier (the original is ABS10U. I know the size is different but it's the only one I had handy) and now the only (and quite obvious) fault is broken inductor L1 located just after 1uF/400V capacitor on the positive rail.

The value I can read is brown, green, red, silver = 1500uH 10%. But I find it troublesome to find 1.5mH inductor in nearby electronic shops. Only 470..680uH.
How essential is the value of this inductor? Can I replace it with other value?

[image: Bottom view of PCB with broken inductor]
[image: Top view of PCB]

Comment: Well, to say that you'll have the same behavior would be false. Whomever designed this board made a decision to choose that inductor value for good reasons. Changing anything that significant (because we're talking about 1mH and not 0.1mH) can change transient and filtering behaviors considerably... That being said, is it not possible to solder down the detached end back to the connector?

Comment: @Colin Unfortunately not, because the part broke on the inside, making it impossible to solder.
The second photo shows that external green body is broken, showing ceramic inside with connecting wire sticking out about 1.5mm

Comment: Using 2 x 680 uH in series should/may work.

Comment: You MAY be able to repair the inductor, and there is little harm in trying. Remove from PCB (power cord removed first :-) :-( ) || Hold inductor in something firm but soft. Hand may do. Pick at broken ceramic with suitable tool. (Tweezer tips may be useful). Flake away material trying to gain access to the broken end. The wire will be VERY fine. If you can expose the end then a solder blob MAY connect just to that. The main danger is in gaining conductivity BUT shorting the inductor and maybe destroying the device on power up. || Or you could make your own. Really. See next comment.

Comment: [This](https://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/inductance.htm) brilliant page tells you how to make inductors in a range of configurations. They mention Wheeler's formula from many decades ago - which works. And much more. || Just did some rough calculations - It almost certainly has a ferrite core, which substantially reduces the turns needed. - 2 x 680 uH may be best. BUT I wonder if it is in fact 1500 uH - probably is, but ... | may be worth checking markings on semi equivalent parts .